# login and register screen in silverlight using wcf web service

Tags: silverlight

i have implemented an application using silverlight mvvm and prism, mef, wcf services, now my requirement is how to use wcf web services to create  **login** and **register** screen to redirect into application . Please suggest a  good approach to do this task

Advance thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is not really a technical question.  It is more of an "How do I create my app" type of question.  That being said, I would try looking at the demo applications on silverlight.net and see if you can find something close to what you are looking for there.  Those usually come with full source code.